# cell in UICollectionView returning nil when trying to change UITextField in that cell from the controller

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I have a UICollectionViewController with a datePicker. When the date is changed, it calls this function:

```
var cell: InfoSection?

@objc func didChangeDate(sender: UIDatePicker) {
    let myDateFormatter: DateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    myDateFormatter.dateFormat = "MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm"

    let mySelectedDate: String = myDateFormatter.string(from: sender.date)
    cell?.dateTextField.text! = mySelectedDate as String
    print("mySelected Date is: ", mySelectedDate as String)
    print("The content of dateTextField is: ", cell?.dateTextField.text!)
}
```

InfoSection is my cell that contains the textField.

cell is showing up as nil at this line:

```
cell?.dateTextField.text! = mySelectedDate as String
```

I'm sure there's a fairly obvious solution I'm missing here. I've tried force unwrapping it - it crashes. I've tried setting the variable cell to a value of `= InfoSection()` - it prints the date in the "context of dateTextField" statement, but doesn't change the textField.

And some SO answers said to change the data in a cell through `cellForItemAt indexPath` which makes sense, but I don't know how to call `cell?.dateTextField.text! = mySelectedDate as String` in `cellForItemAt` whenever `func didChangeDate` is called.

Any help would be amazing! And if you need any other info let me know, thanks!

Comment: You could just store the selected date in an instance var and reload the collectionView in `didChangeDate`. Then in `cellForItemAt` you could use the stored value to update the cell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your should store your selected date as variable and reload your collectionView like this way:

```
var mySelectedDate: String?

@objc func didChangeDate(sender: UIDatePicker) {
    let myDateFormatter: DateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    myDateFormatter.dateFormat = "MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm"

    mySelectedDate = myDateFormatter.string(from: sender.date)
    collectionView.reloadData()
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "CellIdentifier", for: indexPath) as! InfoSection

    cell.dateTextField.text = mySelectedDate
    return cell
}
```

Comment: That worked! I just had to change it to `mySelectedDate = myDateFormatter.string(from: sender.date) as String` and `collectionView?.reloadData()` Thanks for your help!!